# Microsoft Windows equivalent to LXC

Tags: windows-server-2008, lxc

Does Microsoft Windows have any equivalent product similar to Ubuntu's LXC container virtualization technology?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's nothing exactly like Linux containers in the Windows world. [App-V](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/mdop/app-v.aspx) is probably the closest you'll get.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer :-)

Now there is something : Windows Containers & Hyper-V containers

"In a similar way, Microsoft has been adding containerization primitives to the Windows kernel, allowing any user code to execute a process in a sandboxed environment. Those feature are only available in the just released Windows Server 2016 Tech Preview 3 (TP3), which makes it the only Windows Server operating system that is capable of running the Docker daemon today"

Source : Introducing the Technical Preview of Docker Engine for Windows Server 2016  http://blog.docker.com/2015/08/tp-docker-engine-windows-server-2016/

Windows Containers
https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/containers_welcome

Regards

Stanislas

Answer (score 0):

You can create Linux and also Windows containers if you are a windows 10 user. 
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

This uses hyper-v for virtualization and docker containers for containerization.